# Как правильно настроить 301 редирект?

Tags: seo

Доброго времени суток, необходимо настроить 301 редиректы для страниц

1. со страниц с `/index.html` на страницы без `/index.html`
2. со страниц с `/index.php` на страницы без `/index.php`
3. со страницы `site.ru/o-nas/` на `site.ru/o-nas/istoriya/`

   первые 2 у меня получилось настроить только для главной, со всех других страниц с `/index.php` теперь кидает на главную, а с 3 написал `Redirect 301 /o-nas/ http://site.ru/o-nas/istoriya/` но почему то в итоге редирект зацикливается таким образом `http://site.ru/o-nas/istoriya/istoriya/istoriya/istoriya/istoriya/istoriya/istoriya/istoriya/`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пробуйте так:

```
# для первых двух правил
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)/index\.(php|html)$
RewriteRule .* http://%{HTTP_HOST}%1/ [R=301,L,QSA]

# для третьего правила
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/o\-nas/istoriya/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/o\-nas/(.*)$
RewriteRule .* http://%{HTTP_HOST}/o-nas/istoriya/%1 [R=301,L,QSA]
```